# Not Getting proper count for multiple inputs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store mulple rows into database but I am getting only first input value in controller

View page

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city[]">
```

controller code

```
return Input::get('city'); exit;
```

Strange but it returns only first city value

I am getting only first value in array instead of getting 3 values,
I want to add records into database by using count of input like this way..

```
for($i=0; $i<count(Input::get('city')); $i++){
  //database code;
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `$cities = Input::get('city'); dd($cities);`

Comment: I am geting array with first value array:1 [▼
  0 => "Mumbai"
]

Comment: Try Input::get("city.0") Input::get("city.1") as well.

Comment: I am not really sure would this work but have you tried changing the id of the inputs to be unique

Comment: Text inputs do not work like this. They must have unique names. Change the name to `city[1]`, `city[2]`, `city[3]`.

Comment: Yes like this way it is working, but I am adding inputs dynamically so it may be 3, 5 or any number, So I want count in controller such that I can insert multiple records into database. Do you have any idea that how I will get the count easily

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="city_data" id="city_data" value="1"> To get count I have to use one extra hidden field and i am changing its value dynamically when I add one city input by using add button, But I think it is so tricky , suggest me if you have any other easy way of doing this.. Thank You all

Comment: use foreach. you wont have to count your inputs.